# Excel List from non-empty values of a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a list from the non-empty values of a column.

I want therefore to use this list as a dropdown list in other sheets.

The values in this list are dynamic so I can't copy these values in another place.

When I select all values from a column and then create a list from it, when I use it as a dropdown list, I also have the empty values in the list.

Is there a way, without using macros, to automatically remove empty entries from the list?

I don't want to remove the empty cells from the column because it is part of another table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to have another (hidden) column with the values that you want in the drop down list.  If you define a (dynamic) named range of the source data that you want as `List`, then the following formula should be entered in cell `B2` and copied down as required:

`=INDEX(List, MATCH(0, IF(MAX((COUNTIF($B$1:B1, List)=0)*((List<>"")*(COUNTIF(List, ">"&List)+1)))=(IF((List<>""), COUNTIF(List, ">"&List)+1, "")), 0, ""), 0))`

It will even sort the list.

This information was taken from the following site, which has step by step instructions.

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/05/25/create-a-drop-down-list-containing-only-unique-distinct-alphabetically-sorted-text-values-using-excel-array-formula/

Comment: Ok after some little modifications, I managed to make it work, Thanks.

Comment: If you want unsorted, it's a bit easier `=INDEX($A$2:$A$11, MATCH(0, IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$A$11), 1, COUNTIF(B1:$B$1, $A$2:$A$11)), 0))` [link](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/10/how-to-automatically-create-a-unique-list-and-remove-blanks/)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your values are in column `A:A`. Make a column `B:B` with numbers `1, 2, 3, 4...` Then in cell `C1` write formula and drag it down:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL($A:$A,$B1),"")
```

Note: this works only for numeric values.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my request. I want to create a dropdown list from a list of values which are in a column. But I don't want the empty values to be in my dropdown list.

Comment: In that case you will need VBA because number of values in dropdown list cannot be dynamic. Or you can specify larger source for dropdown but you will have blank values at the bottom.

Comment: @Taosique you can have a dynamic list without using VBA.  All you need to do is use the `OFFSET()` function.  If the data is in column A it would be something like `=OFFSET(A1,0,0,COUNTA(A:A),1)`